# WiX - vbscript custom action with session.message function

Tags: vbscript, wix, custom-action

I want to show a dialog to the user that says "this is going to be removed with this installation" and if "YES" or "OK" is pressed, then the installation can continue; otherwise, I want to abort it.

Therefore I have defined a custom action (run vbscript) like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="ShowUninstallInformationDlg" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="ShowUninstallInformationDlg.vb" VBScriptCall=""/>
<Binary Id="ShowUninstallInformationDlg.vb" SourceFile="c:\myscripts\installer\ShowUninstallInformationDlg.vbs"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ShowUninstallInformationDlg" After="FindRelatedProducts">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH AND NOT MYPRODUCT_ANYVERSION=""</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

VBSCRIPT (ShowUninstallInformationDlg.vbs):

```
'ShowUninstallInformationDlg
Option Explicit

Dim text
Dim productName
Dim rec

productName = Session.Property("ProductName")
text = "The following installations are going to be removed with the installation of " & productName & ":"

If Session.Property("MYPRODUCT_ANYVERSION") <> "" Then
  text = text & "\n    * MyOtherProduct (any version)"
End If

Set rec = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(1)
rec.StringData(0) = text

Session.Message &H0B000034, rec
```

The kind "&H0B000034" I am using as "Session.Message" argument is from an example from the MSDN, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371672(v=vs.85).aspx.

Always the script is being executed I get the following error in my MSI log:

> Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action ShowUninstallInformationDlg script error -2147467259, Msi API Error: Message,Kind,Record Line 19, Column 1,

I have searched google massively for examples using Session.Message, but with no succeeding results... Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script solved my issue, by using MsgBox instead of "Session.Message":

```
'ShowUninstallInformationDlg
Option Explicit

const vbOKOnly           = 0    'OK button only
const vbOKCancel         = 1    'OK and Cancel buttons
const vbAbortRetryIgnore = 2    'Abort, Retry, and Ignore buttons
const vbYesNoCancel      = 3    'Yes, No, and Cancel buttons
const vbYesNo            = 4    'Yes and No buttons
const vbRetryCancel      = 5    'Retry and Cancel buttons
const vbCritical         = 16   'Critical Message icon
const vbQuestion         = 32   'Warning Query icon
const vbExclamation      = 48   'Warning Message icon
const vbInformation      = 64   'Information Message icon
const vbDefaultButton1   = 0    'First button is default
const vbDefaultButton2   = 256  'Second button is default
const vbDefaultButton3   = 512  'Third button is default
const vbDefaultButton4   = 768  'Fourth button is default
const vbApplicationModal = 0    'Application modal (the current application will not work until the user responds to the message box)
const vbSystemModal      = 4096 'System modal (all applications wont work until the user responds to the message box)

const vbOK     = 1 'OK was clicked
const vbCancel = 2 'Cancel was clicked
const vbAbort  = 3 'Abort was clicked
const vbRetry  = 4 'Retry was clicked
const vbIgnore = 5 'Ignore was clicked
const vbYes    = 6 'Yes was clicked
const vbNo     = 7 'No was clicked

const msiDoActionStatusNoAction      = 0 '&H0
const msiDoActionStatusSuccess       = 1 '&H1
const msiDoActionStatusUserExit      = 2 '&H2
const msiDoActionStatusFailure       = 3 '&H3
const msiDoActionStatusSuspend       = 4 '&H4
const msiDoActionStatusFinished      = 5 '&H5
const msiDoActionStatusWrongState    = 6 '&H6
const msiDoActionStatusBadActionData = 7 '&H7

public function ShowMessage()
  Dim productName
  Dim text
  Dim buttons
  Dim result

  productName = Session.Property("ProductName")
  text = "The following installations are going to be removed from this computer by continuing the installation of " & productName & ":"

  If Session.Property("MYPRODUCT_ANYVERSION") <> "" Then
    text = text & chr(13) & chr(13) & "    * MyOtherProduct (any version)"
  End If 

  buttons = vbExclamation + vbOKCancel
  result = MsgBox(text, buttons, "Dependant Product Installations")

  If result = vbOK Then
    ShowMessage = msiDoActionStatusSuccess
  Else
    ShowMessage = msiDoActionStatusUserExit
  End If
end function
```

Comment: You don't need vbscript to do what you are doing.  You can use your properties as conditions on ControlEvents to display an MSI dialog.  Doing this in VBScript just makes your installer less reliable by adding a dependency on a technology known to be fragile.

Comment: I've already tried that, but I couldn't interrupt the UI chain with the dialog without forcing it to quit always! Do you have a working example?

Answer (score 4):

I have used following and it worked correctly

```
Session.Message &H04000000, rec
```

Please see the vbs I have written for it

```
  Sub LogMessage(msg)

      Dim rec
      Set rec = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(1)
      rec.StringData(0) = "Custom Message : " & msg
      Session.Message &H04000000,rec

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to show any UI when the Remove button has been pressed in Add/Remove Programs.  Alternatively you can disable the Remove Button and leave the Change Button enabled.   That invokes the Maintenance UI experience that typically has a Repair | Change | Remove dialog.   If they select Remove and press next you can show a rich UI asking your question.

Comment: Hi Christopher, no you got me wrong. I want to display that dialog before initial installation to let the user know that some other products will be removed during the installation. Mainly I want the flexibility to change the text being displayed in the dialog depending on some properties of my setup, therefore I used vbscript.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [this](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-135758.html) post for a similar example and the solution.